# What time is used when I set crontab @daily?

Tags: linux, debian, cron

What time is used by crontab when I use the option **@daily**?
Where is this information stored on Debian/Gnome?
And how can I change this time value?

Comment: @daily is equal to `0 0 * * *`, if you want to change use standard way of crontab.

Comment: @asktyagi Is there a way to double check that, like a file where this default value is stored?

Comment: It is documented in `man 5 crontab`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@daily means **midnight every day**
The information is documented in the manual

```
$ man 5 crontab
```

If you want change this value you can use the first five fields:
**m h dom mon dow usercommand**
0 0 * * * usercommand, means midnight and is the same as @daily